Need to collect payment during event application
I'm trying to setup an event that requires approval - so when a member registers they're set to the "Awaiting Approval" status. When they register, I also need to collect a fee. The amount of the fee never changes and is the same for all events.
Here is the desired event sign-up process for context:

A member "applies" for an event and pays a small application fee.
If they are approved, they are registered for the event and a deposit is required.
Participants are required to pay the entirety of the event fee before arrival.

From I can tell this isn't possible, but I am hoping I'm wrong. Any insight would greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/events/online-event-registration/#participant-approval takes you through all the steps, including the additional Event Participant Statuses that you need to enable, and refers to the Scheduled Job which needs enabled to. As I read it they should then get an email with a link to make payment.

Participants will be placed in 'Awaiting Approval' status. You can review and approve participants from 'Find Participants' - select the 'Change Participant Status' task. Approved participants will move to 'Pending from approval' status, and will be sent an email with a link to complete their registration (including paying event fees - if any).


Note that in order for the status processing to happen, you need to have the Update Participant Statuses scheduled job running (see Administer > System Setting > Scheduled jobs).


In the docs you linked a payment can only be made after the participant is approved. I need to require payment when they initially register for the event, not when they are approved.

sorry didn't read it slowly enough. would it work to just charge them an Application Fee as a contribution, and then send them a link to register if successful?
